# Paypal integration in Oracle XE

Tags: paypal, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am currently using Oracle Express Edition 11g with Oracle APEX. I would like to integrate Paypal in one of my apex applications.

As far as I know, Paypal cannot be integrated in Oracle Express Edition since it requires Wallet. Wallet is available only in Standard Edition.

Since I have APEX APP (which is a Internet Application), I cannot use "Named User Plus" license option, instead should go to "Per Processor" license option & this would cost me a lot.

Is there any other way to integrate Paypal in APEX with Oracle Express Edition 11g?

I did a lot of research about this in the past one week. Looks like it is not possible and integrating Paypal would violate OTN license.

Is there any other payment method that could be used in Oracle APEX with Express Edition? If nothing is available, then I would think about writing a PHP application only for Paypal feature and save the data in Oracle Database whcih could then be accessed by my Apex Application.

Comment: The bad news is if you don't have wallet, you'll be doing this using PHP or some alternate language.  The more hopeful news is that Oracle licensing has taken a leap (for the better) through third-party donors.  Check out my answer below for a quick commentary on the project assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Combining Oracle 11 XE and APEX for Access to Vendor API's (such as Paypal)

> This isn't really an [oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) specific problem.  None of the application design considerations are discussed here.

You may want to take a closer look at the [Paypal RESt API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) which describe specifically how any of several different server side scripting languages can get access to the realm of PayPal functionality.

### Oracle Editions and Licensing Costs

Not knowing the financial or funding situation of the OP, there could be real reasons for not having access to the minimum edition (Standard/Standard-One) to get the functionality of the Wallet feature (which is used for storing encryption keys and certificates used by the RDBMS).

> When you've got something developed to the point that you are ready to run against Paypal's developer "sandbox" (if they have one) *take a look at Amazon's AWS service*.  Their product offering, RDS (Relational Data Store) includes virtual servers with Oracle 11gR2 RDBMS (Standard or Standard One) installed.

### Paying for Oracle Licensing Costs

Read up on their *RDS Oracle licensing program* which is essentially a pay-as-you-go service anchored to an hourly rate.  It sounds scary but if you do the math, the total number of hours in a year alone multiplied by the system usage rate should show the savings from buying an Oracle license through the traditional channels.  Paying a little more up front (~$50/year for a micro instance) puts you into the "reserved" tier which dramatically drops the hourly usage rate.

> Since I first set up Oracle APEX at my last employer, I've been looking on and off for service providers and SaaS-typed businesses that could break the barrier of cost and overhead resources.  This is mainly because there are organizations that could use the APEX platform for assorted business and operational needs... but maybe are unable to afford the costs associated with licensing the Oracle product.

*I'm currently in the process of setting up a persistent, public facing APEX instance.*  Amazon's RDS is currently rated for APEX 4.1 and it presents a good lead in for transitioning my many projects and successes off the "trial and demo" OTN systems (apex.oracle.com) which also forbid the pushing or storage of production or "real" data into their systems.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the lead. Amazon RDS looks good. I currently have a VPS with Oracle XE & Apex installed. I manage this on my own. I don't wish to save my customer data in an external oracle database. I would go for PHP solution for now and may be save the purchase info in Oracle database. Then this can be referred by my APEX application to provide access to user.